# PHP - assigning variable in a foreach loop

Tags: php, variables, variable-variables

I have a variable like this

```
$profile = $adapter->getProfile();
```

Now i'm using it like this

```
$profile->profileurl
$profile->websiteurl
$profile->etc
```

Now i want to use it in a foreach loop

So i created an array like this

```
$data = array('profileurl','websiteurl','etc');

foreach ($data as $d ) {
${$d} = ${'profile->'.$d};
}
```

When I use `var_dump(${$d})` I see only `NULL` instead of values.

Whats wrong?

Comment: What does `var_dump($profileurl, $websiteurl, $etc)` give you?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Functions like extract() are rarely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
${'profile->'.$d}
```

Should be changed to:

```
$profile->{$d};
```

This will create the variables as expected:

```
$profile = new stdClass();
$profile->profileurl = "test profileurl";
$profile->websiteurl = "test websiteurl";

$data = array('profileurl', 'websiteurl');
foreach ($data as $d) {
    ${$d} = $profile->{$d};
}

var_dump($profileurl, $websiteurl);
// string(15) "test profileurl"
// string(15) "test websiteurl"
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `$profile = $adapter->getProfile();` returns an object.  And you have fetched data using `mysql_fetch_object()` so the resulting `$profile` is an object

When you add the properties in an array you will have to do something like this

```
$data = array($profile->profileurl, $profile->websiteurl, $profile->etc);
```

Which will kill the entire idea of doing so.  So i'd suggest better try modifying the `$adapter->getProfile()` method to return an array using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which which will return and array and you can iterate it using

```
foreach($profile as $key => $value){
    //whatever you want to do
    echo $key .  " : " . $value . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why are you approaching foreach. My assumption is, you need 
variable like
$profileurl = "something1", $websiteurl="something2" and more.

```
$profile = $adapter->getProfile();
```

Now just convert $profile object into Array as follows,

```
$profileArray = (array)$profile
```

Then use extract function,

```
extract($profileArray);
```

Now you get values in variable as

```
$profileurl = "something1";
$websiteurl="something2"
```

Then you can use those as normal php variable.